# Extract links (URLs) from database -

Tags: python, database, url, hyperlink, extract

I need to extract all links (URLs) from a database.  Either, using a SQL statement or Python, how can I extract just links from a table?

Sometimes there is no links, sometime 1 and sometime more than 1.

To give an example:

Database name (dbase)
Tables:
id ( int) 
col1 ( has text including URLs)
col2 ( has text including URLs)
col3 ( has text including URLs)
col4 ( has text including URLs)

col1, col2, col3 and col4 contain texts and URLs. (imagen an email contain URLs)

I want to create a new coloum name for example name (URL_found) to have all the URLs found in the col1, col2, col3 and col4.

example

in col1 has 
Hello, Hi this is a test http://www.example.com/somewhereelse/some/where  if you buy this I will get you a free one form

Any idea on how to do that?

THANKS --

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, so here is a broad suggestion. You might need to iterate through the records in your table with a python client, and parse the strings in each column for valid urls, using either a regular expression or some other python parsing library.

Once you find matches for a column or record, you *could* set them to another column `URL_found` with some kind of delimiter between urls...but it would seem to be more useful to create a new db table like `URL_found` with foreign key relations to the records in this original table.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. To be more specific, I have a table (dbase) include 3 columns each column has an email in it, that email is in text format but could also have URLs with the text, what I want is to extract the URLs from the 3 columns and save them (URLs) in a new column name URL_found. What is the proper SQL command to do that, or the Python script to do that? I hope I am clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't really make the question any more specific. That is pretty much what you asked already. I am suggesting that you do it client side. I am not sure that a database is well suited to be trying to do regular expression extractions from text fields. So I suggest iterating over the records with your python client and performing regular expression matches on them. If you had a "this is what I tried" question, then I could comment more specifically on what isn't working with your approach. For now...its just some guidance in a direction for you to try something.